# How to change CSS style of scrollbars of a div section?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have created a div section with a fixed width, while the content in it is overflowing, thus displaying a default horizontal scrollbar for that div. Now I want to style that horizontal scrollbar similar to this example : http://themefuse.com/demo/html/WebStudio/Dark/Green/index.html but without using jquery, code must be using only CSS and Javascript.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of using JavaScript but not a JavaScript library?

Comment: Why not jQuery? jQuery is JS, actually it is built in JS.

Comment: @thirtydot, Harry Joy, xbonez : I know, it very much possible to create such things quickly using JQuery or other such JS libraries. But I want to create the same using pure javascript as we are not using any external libraries in our project.

Comment: @manishekhawat "Not using external libraries" - Really? Jump projects. You wouldn't think of writing a GUI C application without using GTK or QT, so why hamstring yourself here?

Comment: @DavidSouther :) If I were authorized to allow these, I would have, as I love jquery or other such libs. They make life so easy while developing apps. But in this project, we are not allowed to use external libs, as the client says. Unfortunate but true :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ::-webkit-scrollbar css rule that is compatible only with webkit-based browsers. Here you can find a good howto/guide http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: you don't need Javascript, it is a CSS feature.

Comment: thanks for answering. But actually I am looking for a cross browser implementation. Please let me know if you have any idea to make it work cross browser

Comment: there is no cross browser implementation at now with the CSS trick. You could build a "fake" scrollbar as is done in the link referenced by you. See the source of that link there is a Js doing that, here is the URL of the script http://themefuse.com/demo/html/WebStudio/Dark/Green/js/slider.js

Comment: this example uses JQuery. I am looking for a pure javascript/CSS example.